# Where does the term "cube" come from?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, terminology

In Magic, a cube is a collection of cards that is handpicked to make a good draft. A cube draft is a type of limited format that uses a cube to draft from. But what does "cube" mean? Does it refer to a collection of cards in the general sense, or is it Magic-specific terminology? Where did this term originate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Mark Rosewater offered this explanation on his blog](http://markrosewater.tumblr.com/post/104561355723/why-is-it-called-cube-anyway-whats-cubical):

> I believe the first cube was kept in a box that was a cube.

I wouldn't call that explanation definitive, but a quick Google search demonstrates that [there are Magic players who would back up Rosewater's memory](http://www.fantasystrike.com/forums/index.php?threads/mtg-cubes.8451/#post-258620).